# Managing Configuration Across Many Instances of Applications

Tags: azure, architecture, microservices, apache-zookeeper, distributed-system

Disclaimer: I as well as my company are new to developing cloud applications / distributed systems, so this question might have an obvious solution that I'm not aware of.

## Summary of Problem

We are going to have thousands of instances of the same application deployed in brick and mortar locations, this is unfortunate but it's how things have to work for now. These applications will all be deployed on a Windows VM, no K8s clusters or any kind of container based deployment. All of these instances might have to be configured differently, and have those configurations changed by an administrator at any time. Our task is to develop a "Configuration Manager" in the cloud that an administrator user who has zero technical abilities can use and edit for a specific group of application instances. We will be using Azure to host this Configuration Manager. The key here is that each instance of our application can have configuration changes pushed to it individually, not all application nodes will be configured the same.

## Our Current Plan

Today, we are designing a messaging based approach where the Configuration Manager can publish a message to a broker, and then all the application nodes that are listening for a message targeting them will receive that telling them they have to pull a config change from the Configuration Manager. Here is a simple diagram below:

[image: Simple Flow Diagram of Current Solution]

## The Question

I would be curious if any cloud technologies like this exist to solve this problem out of the box today? I know that Apache Zookeeper is intended to be a distributed service config manager, but I haven't dug much into how it would be able to handle fine grained config changes like we require for this solution. If there are any clarifications needed please let me know!

Comment: Do you have to roll out the conf changes near real time? I would assume that a simple periodic polling of the conf would be much easier, e.g. once per hour.

Comment: You could take a look at https://etcd.io/ which is widely used. Basically it is a key/value database, you can watch for changes, and there a tons of clients in existence. If you ask "what is a standard cloud way" to conf management that's probably it as it is used e.g. in Kubernetes.

On the other hand pulling a configuration document from some known location (e.g. a S3 bucket or a GitHub repo) from time to time might just be enough and would mean less infrastructure.

Comment: Thanks @spa, I think etcd might be the solution I'm looking for here. I'll do some research on it

Comment: Does (or, will) the configuration contain any privileged information (e.g. credentials) for one brick-and-mortar location, that other locations should not be able to see? Also, are you doing something like [Salt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(software))?